# How to rewrite .htaccess in local machine?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have this project which is from a remote server.

Then I FTP everything to my local machine which is localhost, then when I type the URL, for example, **localhot/test** it redirects to the production site.

I want that when I type into my localhost not to be redirected to the production site. I think this is somewhere in .htaccess, can someone help me this one?

This is my .htaccess code:

```
 # see if the module is active
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule> 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\*\.test\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.\*\.test\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/test\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jobs\.test\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.jobs\.test\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/test\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Anyway, the project is written in CodeIgniter framework.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try this `.htaccess` http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=htaccess#removing-the-index-php-file

Comment: yes ive tried that htaccess in CI that works but this code above is well modified. dont know how to change and make this thing works in my local machine

Comment: tell me what is your OS and version

Comment: i use windows and xampp for local machine

Comment: make sure you have allowd rewrite url in xampp

Comment: where to check on that?